# custom master page SharePoint online

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

i've create a custom master page , and i wanna apply it for 2 different sites,
with a little change : i wanna only change the banner image for each site , so i'm trying to link it directly from each site assets without making 2 different master pages :
this is my custom master page code :

```
<div id="banner"><img src="what should i put here?" /></div>
```

- here are my  2 sites links :
  1)https://mydomaine.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection/site1/_catalogs/masterpage/images/banner1.png

2)https://mydomaine.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection/site2/_catalogs/masterpage/images/banner2.png

```
<img src="what should i put here?" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to save image with same name in style library or image library of each site , then query using current site context
And assign image src with JavaScript or jquery

```
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    website = clientContext.get_web();
    var list = website.get_lists().getByTitle("library name");
    CamlQuery = "".....
    var items = list.getItems(<CAML Query>);


    onsuccess(){

    var imgsrc = "<get your image url>"
    $('#banner img').attr('src',imgsrc);
    }

   onfailure(){
   }
```

Comment: i didnt undesrtand this piece of code:
        CamlQuery = "".....  (what should i put here?
    var items = list.getItems(<CAML Query>);
var imgsrc = "<get your image url>" what should i put here?

Comment: what should i put in CamlQuery ?

Comment: we have the same name of the image in the style library , so can we retrieve the link of the image using:
var items = list.getItems.getByName("image name") ??

Comment: At least you should know basics of SharePoint coding.... Read about how to retrieve listitem/image using JSOM ...